# ANTLR AST Grammar Issue Mismatched Token Exception

Tags: antlr

my real grammar is way more complex but I could strip down my problem. So this is the grammar:

```
grammar test2;
options {language=CSharp3;}

@parser::namespace { Test.Parser }
@lexer::namespace { Test.Parser }

start   : 'VERSION' INT INT project;

project :   START 'project' NAME TEXT END 'project';

START: '/begin';
END: '/end';

WS  :   ( ' '
        | '\t'
        | '\r'
        | '\n'
        ) {$channel=HIDDEN;}
    ;

    INT :   '0'..'9'+;

    NAME:   ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z')+;

    TEXT  :  '"'  ( '\\' (.) |'"''"' |~( '\\' | '"' | '\n' | '\r' ) )* '"';

    STARTA 
        :   '/begin hello';
```

And I want to parse this (for example):

> VERSION 1 1
>
> /begin    project
>
> testproject "description goes here"
>
> /end
>
> project

Now it will not work like this (Mismatched token exception). If I remove the last Token STARTA, it works. But why? I don't get it.

Help is really appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the lexer *sees* the input `"/begin "` (including the space!), it is committed to the rule `STARTA`. When it can't match said rule, because the next char in the input is a `"p"` (from `"project"`) and not a `"h"` (from `"hello"`), it will try to match another rule that can match `"/begin "` (including the space!). But there is no such rule, producing the error:

> `mismatched character 'p' expecting 'h'`

and the lexer will **not** give up the space and match the `START` rule.

Remember that last part: once the lexer has matched something, it will not give up on it. It might try other rules that match the same input, but it will not backtrack to match a rule that matches less characters!

This is simply how the lexer works in ANTLR 3.x, no way around it.

Comment: Do you know if Antlr4 will fix this? Otherwise I will have to rewrite and rethink big parts of my grammar unfortunateley.

Comment: @metacircle, no, I do not. But if it does, it might still be a while before a stable v4 is released (AFAIK).

Comment: @metacircle, but "merging" multiple id's into a single token is usually a bad idea: such things should often better be handled in a parser rule.